# Official iPhone SDK for Mac needed to test/build RhoHub applications?

Tags: iphone, rhomobile, rhodes

I've seen conflicting information on this.  If I'm using [RhoHub](http://rhohub.com/) (Rhodes) to build an iPhone application, do I need to have a Mac in front of me or use their SDK with some kind of virtualized trickery?  Or does Rhodes include a native Windows solution for testing/deployment?

I'm currently in a Windows XP environment.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Mac. The documentation states that:

> iPhone versions of Rhodes apps need to
>   be built on Mac machines.
>
> Additional **Prerequisites** for
>   iPhone are:
>
> - Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) or greater (Snow Leopard)
> - the iPhone SDK installed (Apple only lets you submit apps for 3.0 or
>     higher, so that is also required for
>     Rhodes, starting with Rhodes 1.2)
> - the XCode IDE(highly recommended but not actually required)

Refer to this document: http://wiki.rhomobile.com//index.php?title=Building_Rhodes_on_Supported_Platforms#Build_Application_with_XCode

Comment: Thanks.  This link assumes a desktop install.  What about via RhoHub, their online development solution?  The following page makes it sound like this can be done online rather than requiring a Mac:

http://rhohub.com/overview

Primary, they seem to have a desktop simulator available for Windows.  Does this interpretation seem correct?  Perhaps their desktop vs online solution is where I'm confused.

Comment: Please update your answer. Apple no longer accepts apps submitted to the store targeting 2.2.<anything>. 3.0 and higher are the only supported apps they accept now.

Comment: @MattB to test a native iPhone application on an iPhone you would need a developer account at Apple and a Mac.

Comment: @MattB The desktop simulator for Rhodes uses Internet Explorer for rendering. So you won't get all effects of web-kit browser. App looks pretty ugly in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like iPhone app development is now possible in Windows.

http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/rhomobile-brings-iphone-app-dev-windows-pcs-100?source=footer